# How to configure In-memory mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, jestjs

I am working with integration testing for my **NodeJS-Typescript** application using a **MongoDB** database. I am using **Jest** as a testing framework. How to replace real db configuration with In-memory database(mongoDb) which I can use for testing. Can anyone help me with the configuration ?

config.ts

```
/**
 * @file Configuration file - Testing Configuration.
 */

export default {
    jwtPrivateKey: '11234.xsdfcswfe.23rcscdsfg',
    // Testing Database configuration
    MongoDB: {
        dbConfig: {
            user: 'xxxx',
            password: 'xxxx',
            host: '11.222.333.444',
            port: '27017',
            authMechanism: 'SCRAM-SHA-1',
            authSource: 'permissionlevel',
            dbName: 'sample_db'
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a real testing database before running the tests & just drop it after running the tests. In this example (using `mongoose`), the database is cleaned even before running the tests (in case something went wrong with the last run)

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testing_db')


const db = mongoose.connection

db.on('error', err => {
        console.error(err.toString())
        done(err)
      })
db.once('open', () => {
        db.db.dropDatabase(() => {
          done()
        })
      })
```

This drops the `testing_db`

Answer (score 0):

I have started using 
[@shelfio/jest-mongodb](https://github.com/shelfio/jest-mongodb) and so far it is working great.

Documentation from their site is great and the repo has decent examples.

It is also the library recommended by jest on their site - [Using with MongoDB](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mongodb) so I’d suggest start looking at this if you haven’t already.

Comment: Yes, I have referred that. In my case i need to connect test db for integration testing. so i need to setup a in-memory configuration in config.ts so that i can avoid beforeAll and afterAll blocks in every test files.

Comment: Ah got you. Not tried a full in memory for that use case but have you considered spinning up an docker MongoDB container then having your tests run against that instance?  Would work just the same and would prevent the additional need for a tear down as it would be destroyed anyway?

Answer (score 0):

After working for some hours. I configured the config.ts which works fine for me.

```
/**
 * @file Configuration file - Testing Configuration.
 */

// configuring In-memory mongodb
const globalAny:any = global;
const inMemoryUri= globalAny.__MONGO_URI__
let uri=inMemoryUri.split('/')
let hostPort=uri[2].split(':')

export default {    
    jwtPrivateKey: '121231231fbuyfg.hfvufuewfr3452',
    // Testing Database configuration
    MongoDB: {
        dbConfig: {
            user:'',
            host: hostPort[0],
            port: '27017',
            authMechanism: 'SCRAM-SHA-1',
            authSource: 'permissionlevel',
            dbName: 'jest'
        }
    }
};
```